# postgresql - CREATE DATABASE foo WITH TEMPLATE bar - some fields missing

Tags: postgresql

I am using the postgresql CLI command `CREATE DATABASE foo WITH TEMPLATE bar;`

It has always previously created an exact copy of `bar`, named `foo`.

I did it again recently, and two fields in a table (`registration_participant`) of `bar` do not appear in `foo`.

Here is the result of:

```
\c bar
\d registration_participant

          Column         |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |
-------------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+ 
<many identical fields not shown>
status_reason            | integer                |           |          |
deregistration_requested | boolean                |           | not null | 
app                      | integer                |           | not null |
```

and here is the result of:

```
\c foo
\d registration_participant

         Column        |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |
-----------------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+ 
<many identical fields not shown>
status_reason          | integer                |           |          |
```

As you can see, those last two fields (`deregistration_requested` and `app`) are missing.

I'm stumped - can anybody tell me why this is happening?

Comment: What version of Postgres server and client-tools are you using?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123240/create-database-with-template-seems-to-lose-relations-in-postgresql - what happens if you run `\dt foo.*` and `\dt bar.*`? Is your `SEARCH_PATH` set correctly?

Comment: Other than a mess-up with `search_path`, that cannot be. Can you construct a reproducible test case?

Comment: my version is PostgreSQL 14.8 (Ubuntu 14.8-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu; no client tools are involved in this, other than the PostgreSQL CLI

Comment: my search path (checked when connected to each database) is `"$user", public`; I don't know whether that is "correct"

Comment: I compared the list of tables with `\dt`, and found many that are missing, but here are some additional strangenesses: a) most of the missing tables are in the copy (`foo`) but one of them is missing from the original (`bar`), b) the missing tables / fields are mostly recently added, but there are other new tables that are not missing. We are using Django 3.2.18 migrations, but that doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Comment: Well, I should have tried it a while ago - a complete reboot of my system cleared the problem, but I have no idea why. So this question is more a curiosity than an urgent problem. I'm going to mark it answered, but if anyone knows how the issue arose, I would still like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot, and try again. CREATE DATABASE makes an exact copy, as expected. Note that simply restarting postgresql does not fix it.